# ProGet not importing npm packages from Drop Path

Tags: node.js, npm, nuget, package-managers, proget

I am in the process of migrating to the latest version of ProGet. I'm currently using version 3.8.6, so am quite far behind the stable release.

I decided to start fresh, moving to a brand new Windows Server 2016 box in AWS, and using RDS for the SQL database.

The new setup is working perfectly, I have imported our NuGet packages by creating a feed, entering a Drop Path and dropping all of the packages there. ProGet picked up on this and moved them all to the Feed.

However, I am now trying to import our npm packages. I've created the feed, added a drop location and moved all the npm packges over. On the old server, they're all already in subfolders. ProGet seems to refuse to add them unless they're in the root folder specified as the Drop Path. So I've moved some packages there (inconveniently they're all called package.tgz...) and it picks them up, moves them to /ProgramData/ProGet/Packages/.npm/F5/ puts them in folder too but then does not become visble in the feed on the web interface.

The package number increases, and if I click packages I can see them all, then click into them and download the package, but it doesn't show up on the main Feed 'Page'.

On the other hand, if I manually upload a package via the web interface, it doesn't put the packages in the same location as above, but it *is* visible on the main feed page... Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? The NuGet packages work perfectly using the same method, so I'm confused as to why npm isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this same behavior when using the bulk upload utilizing the drop path.  From what I can tell, you must have at least one version with the "latest" tag on the details for it to show anything in the Feeds view.